# How can I embed IPython shell into a Python program which uses curses module?

Tags: python, terminal, ipython, ncurses, curses

I'm trying to drop into IPython shell when I press 'i' in my curses program. Upto this point, I set up a curses windows and several other windows. I can interact with the program using a while loop and act upon keystrokes.

From [Embedding IPython](http://heim.ifi.uio.no/~inf3330/scripting/doc/python/ipython/node9.html) I borrowed some code which you can see at the beginning and at the end of the block.

```
...

from IPython.Shell import IPShellEmbed
ipshell = IPShellEmbed()

...

def main():

stdscr = curses.initscr()

(win_maxy, win_maxx) = stdscr.getmaxyx()

onethirds_win_width = int(math.floor(win_maxx/3))
half_win_heigth = int(math.floor(win_maxy/2))

begin_x = 0; begin_y = 0
height = half_win_heigth ; width = onethirds_win_width
download_win = curses.newwin(height, width, begin_y, begin_x)
download_win.border()
download_win.refresh()
download_list_win = download_win.subwin(height-2, width-2, begin_y+1, begin_x+1)

begin_x = (half_win_heigth-1)+2 ; begin_y = 0
height = half_win_heigth ; width = onethirds_win_width
configs_win = curses.newwin(height, width, begin_y, begin_x)
configs_win.border()
configs_win.refresh()
configs_list_win = configs_win.subwin(height-2, width-2, begin_y+1, begin_x+1)

begin_x = 0 ; begin_y = win_maxy-1
height = 1 ; width = win_maxx
status_win = curses.newwin(height, width, begin_y, begin_x)

begin_x = 0 ; begin_y = half_win_heigth+2
height = 1 ; width = win_maxx
input_win = curses.newwin(height, width, begin_y, begin_x)
input_win_textbox = curses.textpad.Textbox(input_win)
#curses.textpad.rectangle(stdscr, begin_y, begin_x, begin_y+height+1, begin_x+width+1)

curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()
stdscr.keypad(1)

stdscr.addstr(half_win_heigth+5, 5, "MCP Fetcher. Ready.")
stdscr.refresh()

while 1:
    c = stdscr.getch()
    download_win.border()
    if c == ord('q'): break  # Exit the while()
    elif c == ord('c'): stdscr.clear()  # Clear the screen
    elif c == ord('i'):
        curses.nocbreak(); stdscr.keypad(0); curses.echo()
        ipshell()  # Start the ipython shell
        curses.noecho(); curses.cbreak(); stdscr.keypad(1)
```

...

and the code continues.

The problem is the IPython shell does not have echo, no cbreak and etc. How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps not relevant to this question in particular, but the docs you linked are from 2005.  Here are [the current embedding docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#embedding-ipython).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. However, I use IPython 0.10.2 and the [documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.10.2/html/interactive/reference.html) is not different, at least the section for embedding.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trick that might help:  [Working with curses in IPython. How can I improve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128691/working-with-curses-in-ipython-a-partial-solution-but)

... it's got some issues, but the basic functionality is there.